# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x558eccb2f0 Chrome_InProcGp

Tags: android, android-webview, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

Our application is running on a custom ROM and the application mainly contain a single webview. Application crashes randomly. We are not able to figure out the scenario in which it's crashing. So far we are pin point the error in the log.

```
04-03 14:41:58.613 3556-4673/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x558eccb2f0 in tid 4673 (Chrome_InProcGp)
```

We figure out this by comparing multiple crash logs.
Our guess is this is something related to the webview version.
Can any one help me out on this ?

```
04-03 14:41:58.613 3556-4673/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x558eccb2f0 in tid 4673 (Chrome_InProcGp)
04-03 14:41:58.673 217-217/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-03 14:41:58.673 217-217/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/rk3368_64/rk3368:6.0.1/MOB30J/user.xiao.20180516.205146:userdebug/test-keys'
04-03 14:41:58.673 217-217/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
04-03 14:41:58.673 217-217/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
04-03 14:41:58.673 217-217/? A/DEBUG: pid: 3556, tid: 4673, name: Chrome_InProcGp  >>> com.example.padapp <<<
04-03 14:41:58.674 217-217/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x558eccb2f0
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007f80138b38  x1   000000558eccb2f0  x2   0000000000000001  x3   0000000000000000
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000001  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000081
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000062  x9   0000007f80138a70  x10  0000000000000003  x11  0000000000000100
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000007f80138b38  x13  000000558eccb2f0  x14  000000558e2c3000  x15  00000000000000a1
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f72e99fa8  x17  0000000000000000  x18  0000007f80138a70  x19  000000558f5a0730
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f72f66f30  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000000000000000  x23  0000007f72f66f60
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000002  x25  0000000000000001  x26  0000007f800f1000  x27  0000007f72f66f90
04-03 14:41:58.761 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000001000  x29  0000007f403ee3c0  x30  0000007f72e4c56c
04-03 14:41:58.762 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f403ee3c0  pc   000000558eccb2f0  pstate 0000000020000000
04-03 14:41:58.772 217-217/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
04-03 14:41:58.772 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000007882f0  [heap]
04-03 14:41:58.773 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000000e568  /system/vendor/lib64/libsrv_um.so
04-03 14:41:58.773 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000676d4  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+52)
04-03 14:41:58.773 217-217/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000001c5c4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
04-03 14:42:00.520 217-217/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
04-03 14:42:00.520 217-217/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
```